# perl regex, ungreedy match somehow not respected?

Tags: regex, perl

What is the reason why this regex to add a license infront of the code in `file.hpp`:

```
perl -i -0pe 's@(.*\n)*?#ifndef@//LICENSE#ifndef@' file.hpp
```

with:

```
    # -0: reads the file into ram (changes file spereator)
    # -p: reads line by line
    # -e: command execution
    # -i: modifiy input directly
```

file.hpp (utf-8 with Unicode BOM):

```
#ifndef GAGA
#define GAGA
asd
asd
#ifndef NDEBUG
```

results in

```
LICENSE#ifndef NDEBUG
```

I dont understand why the non-greedy `(.*\n)*?` matches  till the line NDEBUG?
Why?

Comment: It doesn't when I try. My file results in the first line being `//LICENSE#ifndef GAGA` as expected. Are you sure your `file.hpp` is still the original file? (I.e. you haven't already modified it with garbage using Perl in-place modifications?) Also, your result lacks the leading `//` before `LICENSE`. Does that bother you at all?

Comment: This is so strange: This happens, when ever the encoding of ``file.hpp`` is UTF8 with Unicode BOM. (when I do that then the above applies)

Does somebody know what the problem is?

Comment: Re "*-0: reads the file into ram*", That's not what `-0` does. That's what `-0777` does, which is what should have been used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the problem easier to reproduce, here's a test case with the file contents as a string:

```
$_ = "\xef\xbb\xbf#ifndef GAGA\n#define GAGA\nasd\nasd\n#ifndef NDEBUG\n";
s@(.*\n)*?#ifndef@//LICENSE#ifndef@;
print $_
```

It outputs this:

```
//LICENSE#ifndef NDEBUG
```

indicating that the regexp matched a large portion of the string: `"\xef\xbb\xbf#ifndef GAGA\n#define GAGA\nasd\nasd\n#ifndef"`

Why that match and not some other? First, note that the regexp can't match just `"\xef\xbb\xbf#ifndef"` because:

- If the parenthesized group matches 0 times, there is nothing that can match the `"\xef\xbb\xbf"` part.
- If the parenthesized group matches at least 1 time, the match must include a `"\n"`

Second, the regexp matches this long string starting with the `"\xef\xbb\xbf"` instead of some shorter string starting later in the input because regexps prefer to start the match **as close to the beginning of the input string as possible** and this preference is **stronger than greediness/non-greediness** of any individual quantifier. If a match is found at the beginning of the string, the regexp engine doesn't keep looking. It won't find the other possible match, starting later in the string, that makes the non-greedy quantifier "happier".

So overall, the regexp starts with the beginning of the string, tries to match the non-greedy parenthesized group 0 times, finds that it doesn't work, (because the `"\xef"` isn't a `"#"`), tries to match it 1 time, finds that doesn't work (because the `"#define"` isn't `"#ifndef"`), and so on until it eventually finds that matching it 4 times works, and stops. 4 was the minimum number of repetitions of the non-greedy part that resulted in a match at the beginning of the string.

My preferred strategy for dealing with the curse of the UTF-8 BOM is to strip it off separately before doing anything else.

```
$_ = "\xef\xbb\xbf#ifndef GAGA\n#define GAGA\nasd\nasd\n#ifndef NDEBUG\n";
s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//;
s@(.*\n)*?#ifndef@//LICENSE#ifndef@;
print $_
```

You could merge those substitutions into a single operation, but I like the simple `s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//;` because I can drop it in to almost any script - at almost any line! - and it will at worst do nothing, at best fix a bug.

Side note: you should use `-0777` for whole-file slurping. `-0` alone changes the separator to `"\0"` so it wouldn't do what you wanted if the file contained NULs.